# Extract Date from a Datetime string

Tags: python, date, datetime, parsing, format

I need to get the dates from strings of type `'08-JAN-20 12.00.00.000000000 AM'` in Python. How can I do this?

I tried this:

```
import datetime
datetime.strptime('08-JAN-20 12.00.00.000000000 AM', '%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S %p')
```

but it says time data

`'08-JAN-20 12.00.00.000000000 AM' does not match format '%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S %p'`

Answer (score 0):

Edit string first? For example

```
_string = '08-JAN-20 12.00.00.000000000 AM'
_string = _string.split()[0]
```

The variable now equals '08-JAN-20'. So %d-%b-%y should work.